# How can I fix my Outlook.com to use the right email address

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, outlook.com, microsoft-outlook-365

Outlook.com is supposed to provide a free email address for use with Outlook.live.com within your Microsoft account, but I have been banging my head against a wall for over a week now and I cannot get it to work. And I fear that there is some setting in my browser or local laptop that is making it impossible to fix.

I purchased MS Office 365 Family some time ago and installed it.  Everything work fine, except Outlook which I could not get to work with Outlook.com correctly.  I have uninstalled and re-installed Office 365 several times without luck.  I originally had the account and mailbox names wrong which I thought I had figured out and fixed, but still no luck.

So right now I have Office 365 uninstalled and am concentrating on just getting the Outlook.live.com web page to work.  Currently:

1. I have a working Microsoft account with an Office 365 subscription, under the name @outlook.com.
2. I have accessed from my two laptops and both can access this account
3. On both laptops, from my browser at my MS account page, if I click on the Account Manager circle-button in the upper-right corner it correctly shows my account/email as @outlook.com
4. If I open a new tab and go to Outlook.com:

- On laptop-A it goes to my Outlook.live.com web page, and the Account manager button shows my account/email as <myname>@outlook.com.  However if I try to send an email the message is not sent and it is flagged with the message "The SMTP address has no email associated with it".
- On laptop-B it appears to also goto my outlook.com (has the same old test emails as laptop-B) but the account manager button instead lists my account/email as "outlook_<hexcodes>...".  Here it can correctly send the email to my gmail address.

5. If I go to gmail and reply to this test email (to: <myname>@outlook.com) the outlook.live.com browsers on both laptops receive and can see the message.

So my questions are:

1. What is this "outlook_<hexcodes>..." thing?  Can I change it to <myname>@outlook.com or is this outlook.com's secret internal email address and I have to use it on both laptops?
2. How can I fix laptop-A's email send?  If I need that outlook hex email, how do I get the whole thing from laptop-B (I can only see part of it) and how can I set it into laptop-A?
3. When I re-install Office 365, what do I have to do to get Outlook 365 on Laptop-B to work correctly with all of this?

Comment: Note, I have corrected question 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, [Outlook.com](http://www.outlook.com) and  [Outlook.live.com](https://outlook.live.com/owa/), both links seems will go to the same web page.
[image]

[image]

So, what if you try emptying your Browser cache on laptop-A and re-log into your email account to see if there is any difference. Or you can try some other Browsers for example Microsoft edge or ie.

By the way, seems you also get errors when adding email account to your Outlook desktop client. Are there any error prompts? Please try to provide us with more information related to the issue on your Outlook desktop client for further research.

Comment: First, yes, I tried to indicate in my question that when I goto `outlook.com` it takes me to a specific outlook.live.com site without asking.  In my case it is an `outlook.live.com/mail/...` site rather than OWA.   Second, I did try this from a different browser (Chrome instead of MS Edge) on laptop-A and incredibly it all works correctly without that weird `outlook_HEXCODE...` account name.  However I am loather to wipe my entire Edge cache as I have context on hundreds of sites, is there a way to only wipe the Outlook.com stuff?

Comment: Still looking for guidance on question 3.  The errors/problems were similar to this, either (or both) the account /email names weren't what I wanted and/or send would complain about missing/nonexistent accounts and mailboxes.  However, if I can get the browser Outlook to work, then I will try to Install desktop Office 365 again and see what happens.

Comment: This site (https://www.minitool.com/news/clear-cache-for-one-site.html) explains how to clear a browser's cache for just one site.

Comment: OK, so using the tool above to clear the browser caches as you suggested (but only for outlook.live.com) I have been able to resolve all of my problems with Outlook.com when using the Outlook.live.com browser interface, so I am going to mark this as the correct answer.  If I run into any problems when I re-install desktop Outlook, I will post a separate question.

Comment: Glad to see it could help.